# SQL delete except select result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these 3 tables, and i want to delete from all records except some already used request

1. Registry
2. Record
3. Request

and i use this query which brings me all the rows i want to delete.

```
select *  from Record where RegistryId = 'aa6598'
except
select * from Record where Id in ( select RecordId from Request where RegistryId = 'aa6598')
```

How to use delete in this case?

Comment: Delete from what table?  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all help.

Comment: delete from record

Comment: Does the table Request have a column `RegistryId`?

Comment: Do you mean "I want to delete all records belong to all THREE tables using one command"? Please write any delete command you tried so we understand what you want so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete Record where RegistryId = 'aa6598'
and Id not in ( select RecordId from Request where RegistryId = 'aa6598')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM Record WHERE RegistryId = 'aa6598'
AND RecordId NOT IN( SELECT RecordId FROM Request WHERE RegistryId = 'aa6598')
```

Answer (score 0):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
delete r
from Record r
where r.RegistryId = 'aa6598'
and not exists (select 1 from Request q where q.RecordId = r.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DELETE JOIN`:

```
DELETE FROM rec
FROM (SELECT * FROM Record WHERE RegistryId = 'aa6598') rec
LEFT JOIN Request req
  ON rec.Id = req.RecordId
 AND req.RegistryId = 'aa6598'
WHERE req.RecordId IS NULL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2d8160d72196f94374fe13eccec820df)**